# I am creating a discord bot and my tree commands are not updating with the changes that I am making to them. Why is that

Tags: python, discord.py

I read on a tutorial that you need to add your guild id so that the tree updates on every instance run but that did fix the issue. The tree commands have not update to take the input they are supposed to or the new commands added

```
import discord
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import commands
import config
import os
import events
import groups
import members

'''
This is the main Class that implements the classes groups, members, and events
This class also functions as a GUI for the program

'''

TOKEN = config.bot_token
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=discord.Intents.all())
all_users = []
all_groups = []

client.synced = False
client.added = False

"""
Discord Event On_Ready Constructor to Initialize the Client.
Also initializes the tree commands for the program
"""


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    if not client.synced:
        await client.tree.sync(guild=discord.Object(id=1143632695503638528))
        client.synced = True
    if not client.added:
        client.added = True
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')

"""
This method is a command to create a new member and add them to a list.
"""


@client.tree.command(name="create_member", description="Creates Member")
async def create_member(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    user = interaction.user.name
    newM = members.Member(user)
    all_users.append(newM)
    await interaction.response.send_message(f'"{user}" has been initialized')

"""
This command creates a new group and adds the user as the first member.
It checks if the user is initialized before creating the group.
"""
@client.tree.command(name="create_group", description="Create a group with the user a the only member ")
async def create_group(interaction: discord.Interaction, GroupName: str):
    user = interaction.user.name
    mem = None
    for people in all_users:
        if people.name == user:
            mem = people
            break

    if mem is None:
        await interaction.response.send_message(f'"{user}" not initialized')
        return

    newG = groups.Group(GroupName)
    mem.addGroup(newG)
    all_groups.append(newG)

    await interaction.response.send_message(f'New Group Created, <@{newG.name}>!')


"""
This command adds a user to an existing group,
checking for both the group's existence and the user's initialization.
"""
@client.tree.command(name="add_member_group", description="Adding Usersnames of people in a group")
async def add_member_group(interaction: discord.Interaction, GroupName: str, newUser: str):

    group = None
    for existing_group in all_groups:  # Replace with your list of groups
        if existing_group.name == GroupName:
            group = existing_group
            break

    if group is None:
        await interaction.response.send_message(f'Group "{GroupName}" not found.')
        return

    mem = None
    for people in all_users:
        if people.name == newUser:
            mem = people
            break

    if mem is None:
        await interaction.response.send_message(f'"{newUser}" not initialized')
        return

    mem.addGroup(group)

    await interaction.response.send_message(f'"{newUser}" hase been added to "{GroupName}"')

"""
This command adds a user to This command returns a list of groups that the user is a part of, checking if the user is initialized first.
"""
@client.tree.command(name="my_groups", description=" return the names and the users of groups you are a part of")
async def my_groups(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    user = interaction.user.name
    mem = None
    for people in all_users:
        if people.name == user:
            mem = people
            break

    if mem is None:
        await interaction.response.send_message(f'"{user}" not initialized')
        return

    groups = [group.name for group in mem.groups]
    group_info = '\n'.join([f'Group Name: {group}' for group in groups])
    await interaction.response.send_message(f'You are a part of the following groups:\n{group_info}')

"""
This command returns a schedule of events for the user, considering the user's group memberships.
"""
@client.tree.command(name="my_schedule", description="return your schedule or a the events in your groups ")
async def my_schedule(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    user = interaction.user.name
    mem = None
    for people in all_users:
        if people.name == user:
            mem = people
            break

    if mem is None:
        await interaction.response.send_message(f'"{user}" not initialized')
        return

    schedule = []

    for group in mem.groups:
        for event in group.events:
            schedule.append(event.get_event_info())

    if not schedule:
        await interaction.response.send_message('No events in your schedule or groups.')
    else:
        schedule_info = '\n'.join(schedule)
        await interaction.response.send_message(f'Your schedule:\n{schedule_info}')

"""
This command allows the user to add an event to an existing group
"""
@client.tree.command(name="add_group_event", description="add event to group you are a part of")
async def add_group_event(interaction: discord.Interaction, GroupName: str, EventName: str, year: int, month: int, day: int, start_hour: int, start_minute: int, duration_minutes: int):
    group = None
    for existing_group in all_groups:  # Replace with your list of groups
        if existing_group.name == GroupName:
            group = existing_group
            break

    if group is None:
        await interaction.response.send_message(f'Group "{GroupName}" not found.')
        return

    new_event = events.Event(EventName, group)
    new_event.createEvent(year, month, day, start_hour,
                          start_minute, duration_minutes)
    group.addEvent(new_event)

"""
This command allows the user to remove an event from an existing group,
verifying the group's existence and the event's presence.
"""
@client.tree.command(name="remove_group_event", description="remove event to group you are a part of")
async def remove_group_event(interaction: discord.Interaction, GroupName: str, EventName: str):
    group = None
    for existing_group in all_groups:  # Replace with your list of groups
        if existing_group.name == GroupName:
            group = existing_group
            break

    if group is None:
        await interaction.response.send_message(f'Group "{GroupName}" not found.')
        return

    event_to_remove = None
    for event in group.events:
        if event.name == EventName:
            event_to_remove = event
            break

    if event_to_remove:
        group.events.remove(event_to_remove)
        await interaction.response.send_message(f'Event "{EventName}" removed from group "{GroupName}".')
    else:
        await interaction.response.send_message(f'Event "{EventName}" not found in group "{GroupName}".')
client.run(TOKEN)
```

After running the bot and the this response in the terminal

2023-10-20 14:21:24 INFO     discord.client logging in using static token

2023-10-20 14:21:25 INFO     discord.gateway Shard ID None has connected to Gateway (Session ID: eb846f09f3692f1f936ecb88b8d3e3ca).

MeetupMentor#1586 has connected to Discord!

Then I go to the bot integration in my discord server
the commands that show are
[List as commands as seen on discord](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40Bow.png)

Comment: Where are your commands? Please add enough code so we can identify the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be syncing your commands in the `on_ready()` event. Per the discord.py docs, that function has a chance of being called more than once.

You should setup a command specifically for syncing.

Here is a great example [Umbra's Sync Command](https://about.abstractumbra.dev/discord.py/2023/01/29/sync-command-example.html)

Hope that helps.

Edit: More reasoning why,

Syncing your command tree automatically causes extra unnecessary requests to be made, this is because you only need to sync when commands are updated. What syncing does is send your commands to discord for one guild or globally. If you haven't changed your command's descriptions, added/removed commands, changed names, parameters, etc. you shouldn't sync, since you'd only be updating discord with the commands they already have without doing any changes, which is pointless and a waste of an API request to a limit with an already tight rate limit. Source: [discord.py discords server](https://discord.com/channels/336642139381301249/559455534965850142/1164996128224321678)